# PowerShell / Asp.net c# / Exchange

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server

I'm trying to add users to a Office365 group using PowerShell called from C#.

I've tried the PS script and it works.

When I call it from C# it doesn't...

Here's my script code:

```
$username = "email@domain.com";
$pass_word = "PassWord";
$ListName = "group-mail@domain.com";
$email = "user-mail@domain.com";

$password = ConvertTo-SecureString $pass_word -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList ($username, $password)

Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement
Connect-ExchnageOnline -Credential $psCred

$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $psCred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session

Add-UnifiedGroupLinks -Identity $ListName –LinkType Member –Links $email

Remove-PSSession $Session
```

And the C# code:

```
RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create ();
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace (runspaceConfiguration);
runspace.Open ();

RunspaceInvoke runSpaceInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke (runspace);

string scriptfile = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath (@"scriptFile.ps1");

Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline ();
Command myCommand = new Command (scriptfile);

pipeline.Commands.Add (myCommand);

pipeline.Invoke ();
pipeline.Dispose ();
runspace.Close ();
runspace.Dispose ();
```

Some help? Thanks!

***Anyone?? Help! :)***

Comment: In your Powershell code you are calling Connect-ExchangeOnline and after that you manually create a session. You should just use connect-ExchangeOnline (if you have the correct permissions on Exchange Online this will import all the cmdlets you need). To be honest, for a C# application I would never go for this approach: I would just add members to the group using MS Graph

Comment: Can you show me some examples that I can test? Thanks